# How do I create a custom qml virtual keyboard using VS 2015 and Qt 5.8?

Tags: qt, qml, windows-10, virtual-keyboard

This question is based on **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45033267/qml-virtual-keyboard-add-new-layout)** thread. What I need to know is how to:

> "patch Qt Virtual Keyboard to add your custom layout and then rebuild
> it"

when dealing with a qml project that uses VS 2015 and compiling with msvc2015_64 under 5.8.

- Using Windows 10, VS 2015 w/ qt plugin

What I really need to know is:

What files to add, to edit and what projects to build and where to place those built files in order to get my project to see that custom keyboard.

Also please provide fulls paths, there are a lot of identically named files. Please save me the effort of having to search for the right one.

Comment: In _StackOverflow_ try not to target multiple questions .. ask each question in a different query.

Comment: One question per post, currently your question is too broad.

Comment: There! I simplified my question.